# Checking the graphic of a button

Tags: javafx

I had a question regarding JavaFX and the ability to check a graphic. so within my program, I have a graphics being set for my buttons when the user clicks it.

What I need to find out is what do I need to have inside "temp.getText().equals("O")" and "temp.getText().equals("X")" to make it to where it's checking the button's image name instead of looking for text.

I want the game to say if "X.jpg"(and vice versa for O) is already inside a button then call this error screen popup

```
package sample;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Controller
{
@FXML
private Text winnerLabel;
@FXML
private Button space1;
@FXML
private Button space2;
@FXML
private Button space3;
@FXML
private Button space4;
@FXML
private Button space5;
@FXML
private Button space6;
@FXML
private Button space7;
@FXML
private Button space8;
@FXML
private Button space9;
@FXML
private Button reset;
@FXML
private Text playerLabel;
@FXML
private Text timerLabel;
@FXML
private Image image;
private boolean isGame = true;
private ImageView tempImageView;


@FXML
protected void initialize()
{
    if(isGame)
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                timerLabel.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(timerLabel.getText()) - 1));
                if(Integer.parseInt(timerLabel.getText()) == 0)
                {
                    if(playerLabel.getText().equals("Player 1"))
                    {
                        playerLabel.setText("Player 2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playerLabel.setText("Player 1");
                    }
                    timerLabel.setText(Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(timerLabel.getText()+15)));


                    if(space1.getText() == "X" && space2.getText() == "X" && space3.getText() == "X")
                    {

                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space2.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                        isGame=false;

                    }
                    else if (space1.getText() == "O" && space2.getText() == "O" && space3.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space2.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //vertical
                    else if(space1.getText() == "X" && space4.getText() == "X" && space7.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space4.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if(space1.getText() == "O" && space4.getText() == "O" && space7.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space4.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //diagonal
                    else if (space1.getText() == "X" && space5.getText() == "X" && space9.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if (space1.getText() == "O" && space5.getText() == "O" && space9.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space1.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //vertical 2nd
                    else if (space2.getText() == "X" && space5.getText() == "X" && space8.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space2.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space8.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if (space2.getText() == "O" && space5.getText() == "O" && space8.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space2.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space8.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //vertical 3rd
                    else if (space3.getText() == "X" && space6.getText() == "X" && space9.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space6.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if(space3.getText() == "O" && space6.getText() == "O" && space9.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space6.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //Horizontal 2nd
                    else if (space4.getText() == "X" && space5.getText() == "X" && space6.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space4.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space6.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if (space4.getText() == "O" && space5.getText() == "O" && space6.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space4.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space6.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //Horizontal 3rd
                    else if (space7.getText() == "X" && space8.getText() == "X" && space9.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space8.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if (space7.getText() == "O" && space8.getText() == "O" && space9.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space8.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space9.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    //Diagonal 2nd
                    else if (space3.getText() == "X" && space5.getText() == "X" && space7.getText() == "X")
                    {
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 1 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                    else if (space3.getText() == "O" && space5.getText() == "O" && space7.getText() == "O")
                    {
                        space3.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space5.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space7.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#90EE90");
                        space1.setDisable(true);
                        space2.setDisable(true);
                        space3.setDisable(true);
                        space4.setDisable(true);
                        space5.setDisable(true);
                        space6.setDisable(true);
                        space7.setDisable(true);
                        space8.setDisable(true);
                        space9.setDisable(true);
                        winnerLabel.setText("Player 2 has won, click reset to play again.");
                        timer.cancel();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
    }
}


/*
This method is the part of the program that will get which of the 9 buttons was clicked and based on who's player turn it is will change the text of the button to either an
X for player 1 or an O for player 2. afterwards the second player will go
 */
public void playTile(ActionEvent e)
{
    Button temp = (Button)e.getSource();
    Image tempImageX = new Image(getClass().getResource("X.jpg").toString());
    Image tempImageO = new Image(getClass().getResource("O.png").toString());

    if(temp.getText().equals("X"))
    {
        try
        {
            Stage screen1 = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("errorScreen.fxml"));
            screen1.setTitle("Error!");
            screen1.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
            screen1.show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else if (temp.getText().equals("O"))
    {
        try
        {
            Stage screen1 = new Stage();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("errorScreen.fxml"));
            screen1.setTitle("Error!");
            screen1.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
            screen1.show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!temp.isDisable())
        {
            if (playerLabel.getText().equals("Player 1"))
            {
                playerLabel.setText("Player 2");
                tempImageView.setImage(tempImageX);
                temp.setGraphic(tempImageView);
                tempImageView.setId("X");
            }
            else
            {
                playerLabel.setText("Player 1");
                tempImageView.setImage(tempImageO);
                temp.setGraphic(tempImageView);
                tempImageView.setId("O");

            }
        }
    }
}
/*
This method is the functionality of the reset button when clicked it will 
reset all the 9 "Tiles" buttons text to blank and from that also reset the 
player label back to "Player 1:
to continue the game.
*/
public void resetButton(ActionEvent event)
{

    playerLabel.setText("Player 1");
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initialize();
            timer.cancel();
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 1000, 1000);
    winnerLabel.setText("");
    space1.setDisable(false);
    space2.setDisable(false);
    space3.setDisable(false);
    space4.setDisable(false);
    space5.setDisable(false);
    space6.setDisable(false);
    space7.setDisable(false);
    space8.setDisable(false);
    space9.setDisable(false);
    space1.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space2.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space3.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space4.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space5.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space6.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space7.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space8.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space9.setTextFill(Paint.valueOf("000000"));
    space1.setGraphic(null);
    space2.setGraphic(null);
    space3.setGraphic(null);
    space4.setGraphic(null);
    space5.setGraphic(null);
    space6.setGraphic(null);
    space7.setGraphic(null);
    space8.setGraphic(null);
    space9.setGraphic(null);
   }
}
```

Comment: An `ImageView` does not save reference to the image's filename, so unless you store the filename in a variable somewhere, you will not be able to retrieve it. Instead, adding a property to the `Button` as Sai Dandem's answer below illustrates may be a feasible option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the question, you dont want to set the text to the buttons and you want to check what button it is based on the graphic it has(either X or O).

If this is the question, I would recommend to set/update a property of the button based on the type of the image/graphic it is holding, something like

```
button.getProperties().put("TYPE","X"); //  For X button
button.getProperties().put("TYPE","O"); //  For O button
```

And you can check directly for the type, rather than accessing the graphic. like..

```
if(space1.getProperties().get("TYPE").equals("X") && space2.getProperties().get("TYPE").equals("X") && ...){
...
}
```

Alternatively you can utilize the setUserData() method of the Node which internally uses the above logic only. If you go with userData your code will be less verbose also.

```
button.setUserData("X");

if(space1.getUserData().equals("X") && space2.getUserData().equals("X") && ...){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to keep the file name information in an `ImageView` or `Image`. Of course, you can always extend from either of these 2 classes and store the file name as a field, but you probably don't need that.

You can also keep the references of the two `Image` instances and check for reference instead.

```
Image imageX = new Image(getClass().getResource("X.jpg").toString());
Image imageO = new Image(getClass().getResource("O.png").toString());

public void playTile(ActionEvent e)
{
    // Other stuff

    Image currentImage = tempImageView.getImage();
    if (currentImage == imageX || currentImage == imageO) // Checking for reference
    {
        // Your logic
    }
    else
    {
        // Your logic
    }
}
```

The most interesting thing here is that all you wanted to do is to check whether the "tile" has been filled. The simplest way to do this is actually to do `if (tempImageView.getImage() == null)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the file name of a button's set graphic:
In this example, when you click on a button, it will execute code in the if statement when the image file source name matches an indicated string (the file name you are comparing)

Note: If the button has not had a graphic set, attempting to use the contains method as used below will cause a NullPointerException. It is advisable to surround the code in a try/catch block if this risk applies in your situation.

```
public void handler(ActionEvent e)
{
//image file you want to check
    String name = "X.jpg";

//button reference within handler
    Button button = (Button)e.getSource();

//ImageView reference from button
    ImageView buttonGraphic = (ImageView)button.getGraphic();

//check if buttons image file directory contains X.jpg
    if(buttonGraphic.getImage().getUrl().contains(name))
    {
        System.out.println("Button has image X.jpg");
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added a note to the post about the risk, thank you.  @kleopatra

Comment: good, thanks - but you might consider making the code itself more robust by adding a null check :) which wouldn't require (nor should it be) a try-block, btw: null url is no exception but a valid state